# JAVA - Charcater Conversion from text file (UTF-16 to UTF-8)

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA. I wanted a JAVA code to convert a text file coming from Unix to a text file that goes to Linux server. So, its a character conversion code from UTF-16 TO UTF-8. The text file goes tthrough oracle database before it reaches linux server. I need this conversion because some special symbols are getting converted to garbage values. Please help Java Experts :)

Comment: Thank you. I am totally new to JAVA. I was wondering how is it done for a text file ? Please advise.

Comment: pls give some example code if possible

Comment: Read the file with `Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_16)`.  Write the data using `Files.newBufferedWriter(newPath)` (which implicitly uses UTF-8).  You can also store the data directly in the database, if you’re using JDBC, with [Clob.setCharacterStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#setCharacterStream-long-) so the output character set won’t be an issue.

Comment: tutorial from the [Essential Classes Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/index.html) : [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)

Comment: An example code would really help me since I have very little time. Thanks for the link though

Comment: I am sure that I probably (statistics) have less time than you!

Comment: What is this code doing?                                                               BufferedWriter outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fOutputFile, true));

Comment: No problem Carlos! You have a good day! I am trying to find help from others as well :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: Good Morning. InputStream/OutputStream-family are used to read/write **bytes**; Reader/Writer-family to read/write **characteres**. The later ones are normally created using the first ones as source/consumer. (The FileWriter is an exception, it internally creates an OutputStream.) Between *Stream and Reader/Writer is the Charset encoding/decoding, if none given the platform's default is used. The Buffered version is just adding a buffer for reading/writing, recommended for efficiency avoiding frequent converter invocations. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)